# Looping through array for Tabulator

Tags: tabulator

I have an array that I am attempting to push into a table using tabulator...

My dataTable line reads as followed..

```
var tableData = [<?php $array = print json_readable_encode ( pulseProxyStatus ( $uri, $authtoken ));?>];
```

This presents me with an empty table.  However, If I specify a specific record from the json array, it will show me that one record, but I cannot see the entire result.

```
var tableData = [<?php $array = print json_readable_encode ( pulseProxyStatus ( $uri, $authtoken )[8]);?>];
```

How can I get this table to show the entire result of the JSON array.  Do I need to loop through somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have all the data available loop over it and create an array as in the image below and set it using table.setData(tableData) as in [documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/data#array)

[image]